# Try to find the hidden letters!

Tags: logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

Try to find the hidden letters!

Tips: ▲

1: (1/2)π^2

2: (2πr) + 2r

3: (2πr) + 4r

Comment: The hint is delta so the missing letters have something to do with the change between hints?

Comment: @Forklift The tip is a filled-in triangle, not necessarily a delta. It may suggest using trigonometry or some other geometry.

Answer (score 2):

1/2 π^2 = half g (acceleration due to earth gravity)

(2πr) = o (circumference) + 2r ( diameter )  = θ

(2πr) = o (circumference) + 4r ( twice diameter ) | = o + | = d

> SO is the answer = half god  == demi-god..

Comment: nope! But nice try!